# JButton.setToolTiptext causing UI freeze

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I am trying to add `JButton` and setting Tooltip to the button on a `JPanel`. It basically goes like this

```
public class CustomPanel extends JPanel{

public CustomPanel(){
..
initGraphics();
...
}

public void initGraphics(){
    JButton button1 = new JButton("button1");
    JButton button2 = new Jbutton("button2");
    button1.setToolTipText("hello1");
    add(button1);
    add(button2);
}
```

When i run the program and mouse over on the button1, UI is getting freezed for 3 seconds or so and no tooltip is being shown.

Can somebody tell me what i am missing?

Comment: maybe you are doing something heavy on a main thread?

Comment: Having the rest of the GUI code would possibly be handy :)

It's likely that you're doing work on the EDT, which prevents the visual update from occurring.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use ToolTips](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) for working examples. Either start with working code and make changes for your requirements, or compare your code with the working example.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).